# Is an increase in variability of the per-sample loss values a sign of overfitting?

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting, bias-variance-tradeoff

I trained a couple of vanilla U-Nets at depths of 1, 2 and 3 (by depth I refer to down max-pooling steps) and different numbers of filters.
Running on the validation data I get the following graphs for mean and standard deviation of the sample BCE values:

[image]

[image]

Now:

Looking only at the mean BCE, I could conclude that models with ~470k parameters are the best, since going beyond this size the mean BCE starts to increase.
However, the standard deviation starts increasing already before that and has its minimum at model-sizes of ~120k parameters.

So which one of these models is best in the sense, that it has the lowest overfitting with good performance?

Bonus question: Is the increase in standard deviation an (earlier) manifestation of bias-variance-tradeoff?